# Image upload automation using flutter integration test

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-integration-test

How we can automate image picker and file picker (file upload event) in flutter apps using flutter integration test??

I tried with patrol but it is not applicable for web ?? is there any other solution??

Answer (score 1):

> You Can Mock Method channel I'm assumeing that you are using
> Filepicker to pick file from your device

***main.dart***

```
TextButton(
           onPressed: _pickFile,
              child: Text('Open file picker'),
            ),
```

***and define your _pickFile method to pick file.***

```
 Future<void> _pickFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    final path = result?.files.single.path;
    if (path != null) {
      setState(() {
        final file = io.File(path);
        _files.add(file);
      });
    } else {
      print('User canceled the picker');
    }
  }
```

> And now in your test file mock filepicker package:

```
import 'package:anotherapp/main.dart' as mainapp;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:integration_test/integration_test.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  mockFilePicker() {
    const MethodChannel channelFilePicker =
        MethodChannel('miguelruivo.flutter.plugins.filepicker');

    TestDefaultBinaryMessengerBinding.instance?.defaultBinaryMessenger
        .setMockMethodCallHandler(channelFilePicker,
            (MethodCall methodCall) async {
      final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/pic.png');
      final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
      final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final File file = await File(
        '${tempDir.path}/tmp.tmp',
      ).writeAsBytes(bytes);
      print(file.path);
      return [
        {
          'name': "pic.png",
          'path': file.path,
          'bytes': bytes,
          'size': bytes.lengthInBytes,
        }
      ];
    });
  }
  setUp(() {
    mockFilePicker();
  });

  testWidgets(
    'selects an image using a native file picker',
    (tester) async {
      mainapp.main();
      await tester.pumpWidget(const mainapp.MyApp());

      expect(find.text('Open file picker'), findsOneWidget);

      await tester.tap(find.text('Open file picker'));

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.byKey(const Key('image_0')), findsOneWidget);

      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));

      
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain which widget has key of 'image_0'? Is it a FileImage/AssetImage which is being shown in the screen?